# Getting non-unique results from METIS when different compiler is used

Tags: graph, partitioning, metis

I'm trying to use [METIS 5.1.0](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) for partitioning large graphs. I have compiled METIS source code in Windows (using Cygwin), Linux (using gcc), and Mac (using different version of gcc). Unfortunately, the results that I get in various platforms are significantly different. Even I tried two different versions of Cygwin on Windows and surprisingly that affected the results too. On the other hand, using the same binary on different machines (same platform) gives unique results.

I understand that METIS performs graph partitioning using heuristics but this compiler/platform dependency is not acceptable in my use case. I have developed a Java application which calls METIS binary file and it's quite important for me to get the same result across various platforms.

Comment: could you share the git link here? I know this is a too old post, but still, I am hoping for a positive response. Thanks @Javad